# Threejs , imported .objs get stretched, they don't conserve their real size

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a threejs project , I'm importing bunch of .objs, the problem is that they don't appear with their real size, I know it's a camera aspect or renderer issue, here is the code for camera and renderer :

```js
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(48,(window.innerWidth)/(window.innerHeight),0.1,3000)
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.getElementById("myCanvas"),antialias:true,alpha:true})
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

Comment: Do the OBJs appear with the right dimensions when added to threejs.org/editor/? Does the proportions change if you resize the window? The few lines of code you've shown so far do look right.

Comment: you might find [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-obj.html) useful